# Consume Java weblogic web service having usernametoken and client certificate in ASP.Net

Tags: java, asp.net, x509certificate, wse, usernametoken

i need to consume a web service developed with java web logic server, usernametoken and client certificate are used to invoke the service.
and i got the java code to call web service as below

```
import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.ejb.SessionBean;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TPException;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TypedString;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.Reply;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TuxedoReply;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TPServiceInformation;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TypedFML32;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TuxedoService;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TypedBuffer;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import MMSWbSrv.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import weblogic.security.SSL.TrustManager;
import weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider;
import weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityContext;
import weblogic.wsee.security.bst.ClientBSTCredentialProvider;
import weblogic.wsee.security.unt.ClientUNTCredentialProvider;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import weblogic.wsee.security.util.CertUtils;
import javax.xml.rpc.Stub;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.*;
import weblogic.wtc.jatmi.TypedFML32;
public class MMSTest
{
public static void main(String args[])  throws Throwable
{

        Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
        sysProps.setProperty("http.proxyHost","XXX.XX.X.XX");
        sysProps.setProperty("http.proxyPort","XXXX");
        sysProps.setProperty("weblogic.webservice.transport.http.proxy.host", "XXX.XX.X.XX");
        sysProps.setProperty("weblogic.webservice.transport.http.proxy.port", "XXXX");
        sysProps.setProperty("http.proxySet","true");
        sysProps.setProperty("weblogic.webservice.verbose","true");

        sysProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","D:/weblogic92/server/lib/DemoTrust.jks");

        System.out.println("proxyHost::"+ sysProps.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
        System.out.println("proxyPort::"+ sysProps.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));

        MMSService service = null;
        MMSPortType port =   null;

        try{
            System.out.println("before..");
            service = new MMSService_Impl("http://XXX.XX.X.XX/MMS/Service?wsdl");
            System.out.println("after..");
            if(service==null)
                System.out.println("NULL SERVICE");
            System.out.println("got service...");
             port = service.getMMSServicePort();
            if(port==null)
                System.out.println("NULL PORT");
        }
        catch(ServiceException svcEx)
        {
            System.out.println("In ServiceXexception");
        }

        List credProviders = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("After cred");

        String clientCertFile = "F:/client-cert.der";
        String keyFile = "F:/client-key-pkcs8.der";


        String username = "userName" ;
        String password = "Password" ;

        CredentialProvider cp = new ClientBSTCredentialProvider(clientCertFile, keyFile);

        credProviders.add(cp);

        System.out.println("credProviders:"+credProviders);
        System.out.println("cp:"+cp+":");

        String strret= "";
        try{


            cp = new ClientUNTCredentialProvider(username, password);
            credProviders.add(cp);
            Stub stub = (Stub)port;
            System.out.println("before");
            stub._setProperty(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credProviders);
            System.out.println("after");
            stub._setProperty(WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER,
                new TrustManager()
                {
                    public boolean certificateCallback(X509Certificate[] chain, int validateErr)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            );

        String strArg = "Parameters";
        strret = port.sendData(strArg); 

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("JJJ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        System.out.println("strret:"+strret);
}
}
```

and also .pfx format client certificate and .key file .
So using WSE3.0 i try to consume the service like below

```
  WebReference.MMSServiceWse wse = new MMSServiceWse();
        UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("XXXX", "XXXX",             PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
        wse.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\\certificate.pfx","",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        wse.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        wse.SetPolicy("ClientPolicy");
        //System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy =new      TrustAllCertificatePolicy();
        String strArg = "Param";
       strArg= wse.sendData(strArg);
```

but i have got exception.

Comment: what exception, add more details

Comment: exception System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Unknown exception, internal system processing error.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, it is usually because the time on the server and the client are too different. The security token has a validity period and if you're not in sync, it seems expired or worse, in the future.